# magento top searches - trailing slashes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

“5 Most Recent Searches” and popular searches page is full of search terms that have “slashes” appended to them:

’{search_term}’, ’{search_term}/’, \’{search_term}//’ ...  ’{search_term}///////////////////////’

does anyone know if its a Magento bug?
any idea what may cause this problem?

I'm using Magento 1.7

Answer (score 0):

We are running a number of shops on v 1.7 and  never encounter such issue. My guess is that some crawler attacks your search form with a list of poorly generated searches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why my previous post with solution was deleted, but anyway... This is problem with web crawler. Try to find which one is messing your search function in your store and try to block it.

Comment: Looks like its "Ahrefs Web Crawler". Thanks tor advice.